# Thumbnails with a jQuery hover and social icons?

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, hover

I am looking for a jQuery plugin or tutorial to have a hover effect on thumbnails. I would like to display a title over the image, social icons and a link. There would be a greyscale over the picture and display the text and icons above it?

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks all,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two tutorials probably cover the majority of functionality you're looking for

- [Display tools tips with a jQuery plugin](http://yensdesign.com/2009/01/how-to-display-tips-creating-jquery-plugin/)
- [A simple mouseover hover effect with jQuery](http://bavotasan.com/2009/a-simple-mouseover-hover-effect-with-jquery/)

And here's a plugin that does image greyscaling

- [Greyscale plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/GreyScale)

Comment: I would like to have an image, that when you hover over it, the image goes grey and then it displays a title and social links on the grey image.

Answer (score 0):

I found this tutorial for hover effects.

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/11/02/original-hover-effects-with-css3/